# Blocking IE 7 / IE 8 compability mode users?

Tags: php, browser

On our website we currently implemented logic to block IE 6 users. But IE 7 is equally crappy and it requires a lot of work to make the stylesheets work so we are deciding if we block IE 7 will this affect IE 8 users who run compatibility mode (which mimics IE 7) or will it only block people who have Ie 7 installed? I would like to block only people who use IE 7 but allow people who use IE 8 in compability mode but display a warning to them that this site requires pure IE 8. Or to make life easier i could block IE 8 in compability mode? And if so how to do this compability mode check in php?

Comment: Not sure of the figures, but I'm pretty certain that IE7 still commands 10% market share, so is that wise?

Comment: @Richard - http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201004-201104 is a useful view of browser/version usage... IE7 is currently running at about 7%

Comment: @Mark Baker: Thanks for the stat.

Comment: @Richard If people would finally stop supporting it, maybe people would finally start upgrading. I block everything under IE8. I even blocked IE8 for a while.

Comment: @tylermwashburn - would you block users based on the colour of their skin, or their IQ? At the very least, degrade your website for users who aren't technically savvy enough to know how to install the latest version of a web browser.

Comment: @tylermwashburn: If your website's security depends on the client doing *anything* a particular way, that's a site I'd want to stay far away from. You should block a browser if *dealing with supporting it* is too much of a burden. If you're relying on the browser to form a part of your security, then you don't have security.

Comment: @Adam It's just as an example. It's more that I'm sick of having to write 3x as much code, for less effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent IE to not render in compatibility mode by adding the following to your .htaccess file:

```
Header set X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
```

This will tell IE to always render the page to the latest version of IE (edge)

This is discussed further here : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

alternatively you can add the following in the header of the pages you wish not to be used in compatibility mode :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" >
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not block visitors based on the browser they use. Create the website in such a way that it works with all browsers. Use [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) to provide usability enhancements for people that use browsers with better support for current web standards.

Answer (score 0):

When IE8 goes into Compatibility mode it acts just like IE7.

That means that if you allow IE8 in Compatibility mode to enter, then you're pretty much allowing IE7.